# Uncaught ReferenceError: calculator is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript

Developer tools/troubleshooting tells me that calculator is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick. Everything works except that I don`t get an answer. Do anyone see what I am doing wrong? I follow an example, an the example works. But not my code. I get four buttons, and two textfields, but not an answer when I click on the buttons, with number in the textfields.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
         <head>
           <title>oppg.3</title>
         </head>
       <body>

         <input id="v1" type="text" style="width:5em;"/>
         <button onclick="calculator.sum();"> + </button>
         <button onclick="calculator.multiply();"> * </button>
         <button onclick="calculator.div();"> / </button>
         <button onclick="calculator.mod();"> % </button>
         <input id="v2" type="text" style="width:5em;"/>
         <span id="result"> </span>


       <script type="text/javascript">
    var Calculator = function(inp1,inp2,reslt) {
        this.valinp1 = inp1;
        this.valinp2 = inp2;
        this.result = reslt;
        if (!Calculator.prototype.sum) {
          Calculator.prototype.sum = function() {
            var value1 = Number(this.valinp1.value),
                value2 = Number(this.valinp2.value);

                this.result.innerHTML =
                 (!/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) || !/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)))
                 : (value1 + value2);
            };
            Calculator.prototype.multiply = function() {
              var value1 = Number(this.valinp1.value);
              var value2 = Number(this.valinp2.value);
              this.result.innerHTML =
                (!/[0-9]/.test(string(value1)) || !/[0-9]/.test(string(value1)))
                :(value1*value2);

            };
            Calculator.prototype.div = function() {
               var value = Number(this.valinp1.value);
               var value2 = Number(this.valinp2.value);
               var restmp = value1/value2;
               this.result.innerHTML =
                 (!/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) || !/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) || value2 === 0)
                 : restmp%1 ? restmp.toFixed(3) : restmp;
            };
            Calculator.prototype.mod = function() {
              var value1 = Number(this.valinp1.value);
              var value2 = Number(this.valinp2.value);
              var restmp = value1%value2;
              this.result.innerHTML =
              (!/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) || !/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) || value2 === 0)
              : value1%value2;

            };
          }
      };
      calculator =
         new Calculator (
             document.getElementById('v1'),
             document.getElementById('v2'),
             document.getElementById('result')
        );
        </script>


      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Give us the whole code, calculator included.

Comment: because there is no object called calculator - guess you'll have to write it

Comment: Have posted the entire code now, @paqash.

Comment: @Zappoh did you look at my answer?

Comment: Looked at it now, it was the case mismatch @paqash. Maybe I overlooked your answer the first time I posted it, since I`m new to the site, and thus reposted the question. Where I got the same answer...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working snippet, you had some typos and syntax errors in your validation code.

```js
var Calculator = function(inp1,inp2,reslt) {
        this.valinp1 = inp1;
        this.valinp2 = inp2;
        this.result = reslt;
        if (!Calculator.prototype.sum) {
          Calculator.prototype.sum = function() {
            var value1 = Number(this.valinp1.value),
                value2 = Number(this.valinp2.value);

                this.result.innerHTML =
                 (!/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) || !/[0-9]/.test(String(value1))) ? 'error'
                 : (value1 + value2);
            };
            Calculator.prototype.multiply = function() {
              var value1 = Number(this.valinp1.value);
              var value2 = Number(this.valinp2.value);
              this.result.innerHTML =
                (!/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) || !/[0-9]/.test(String(value1))) ? 'error'
                :(value1*value2);

            };
            Calculator.prototype.div = function() {
               var value1 = Number(this.valinp1.value);
               var value2 = Number(this.valinp2.value);
               var restmp = value1/value2;
               this.result.innerHTML =
                 (!/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) || !/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) || value2 === 0)
                  ? restmp.toFixed(3) : restmp;
            };
            Calculator.prototype.mod = function() {
              var value1 = Number(this.valinp1.value);
              var value2 = Number(this.valinp2.value);
              var restmp = value1%value2;
              this.result.innerHTML =
              (!/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) || !/[0-9]/.test(String(value1)) || value2 === 0) ? 'error'
              : value1%value2;

            };
          }
      };
      calculator =
         new Calculator (
             document.getElementById('v1'),
             document.getElementById('v2'),
             document.getElementById('result')
        );
```

```html
<input id="v1" type="text" style="width:5em;"/>
         <button onclick="calculator.sum();"> + </button>
         <button onclick="calculator.multiply();"> * </button>
         <button onclick="calculator.div();"> / </button>
         <button onclick="calculator.mod();"> % </button>
         <input id="v2" type="text" style="width:5em;"/>
         <span id="result"> </span>
```